# How to add a filter to remove (Blanks) from a column?

Tags: office-js

I have a table with 140 columns. Trying to add a filter to remove all the rows with (Blanks) in all of those columns. How to add a filter for (Blanks)?

Tried adding a value filter with values `['<0', '>0', '0']` for some columns since they were numeric, but it didn't work. Also noted that clearing filters on all the 140 columns is way too slow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should allow you to add a filter that removes blank values from a column :

```
Excel.run(function(ctx) {
    ctx.workbook.tables.getItemAt(0).columns.getItemAt(0).filter.applyCustomFilter("<>");
    return ctx.sync();
});
```

Regarding the "clearing filters" being slow, would you mind expanding on that? Are you calling `table.clearFilters()` or clearing all the columns individually?

Comment: The custom filter doesn't look like working to me. I am seeing all the rows are hidden regardless if there are values or not. I am adding the filters for all columns in the table except two in a loop.

The `table.clearFilters()` did improve performance compared to clearing individual filters in a `ctx.sync()`.

Comment: Hmmmm, the above code is working for me. Would you mind giving me a sample of your data and your code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It was my mistake, I was adding the filter on all columns. Only first column had values in some rows. Are there any way to add "Or" condition between all columns? Like the row should be hidden only if no column have value in the row.